# Leap Motion Get Finger Bending (C#)

Tags: c#, leap-motion

Hello I tried a lot diffrent ways to get bending angle in Leap Motion. But I couldn't get true values. I used this method for reading. Thanks in advance.

```
Bone bone1 = finger.Bone(Bone.BoneType.TYPE_INTERMEDIATE);
Bone bone2 = finger.Bone(Bone.BoneType.TYPE_PROXIMAL);
double angle = 180 - ((bone1.Direction.AngleTo(bone2.Direction) / Math.PI) * 180) * 2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example I'll use array accessors as a quicker way of accessing bones from Finger objects.

For reference, bone indices are: 0 = metacarpal, 1 = proximal, 2 = intermediate, 3 = distal. You can validate this by looking at the definition of BoneType.

(Careful, the thumb has one fewer bone than the other fingers.)

```
Vector3 bone0Dir = finger.bones[0].Direction.ToVector3();
Vector3 bone1Dir = finger.bones[1].Direction.ToVector3();

float angle = Vector3.Angle(bone0Dir, bone1Dir);
```

This example retrieves the angle in degrees between the metacarpal bone and the proximal bone of the `finger` object.

Note that Vector3.Angle returns the *unsigned* angle between the two bones; if you desire a signed angle, you can use the `SignedAngle` function instead. You'll need to pass it a reference axis; `Vector3.Cross(hand.PalmarAxis(), hand.DistalAxis())` would be suitable for this.

---

EDIT: Ah, apologies, the answer is a bit different if you're outside of the Unity engine. In that case, Leap.Vector.AngleTo is sufficient, but there's a simpler way to convert radians to degrees:

```
Vector bone0Dir = finger.bones[0].Direction;
Vector bone1Dir = finger.bones[1].Direction;

float angle = bone0Dir.AngleTo(bone1Dir) * Vector.RAD_TO_DEG;
```

Again, this will return the unsigned angle, but fingers don't usually bend backwards, so this should be sufficient for your use-case. You can also use `Math.Asin((bone0Dir.Cross(bone1Dir).Magnitude)) * RAD_TO_DEG` to get a (right-handed) signed angle.

Comment: Added an answer for a situation outside the Unity engine using Leap.Vector functions and a function from the standard .NET math library.